# How to display specific years only on xAxis in a column-graph with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels, column-chart

Having trouble to display only the two selected years in my column chart. It always adds other years to it and the chart looks terrible. It should display "2007" and "2010", but shows "2006", "2008" and "2010". I guess it's a small thing to change, but I can't figure out what that would be.

[Here is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/3bcb8sxw/2/) and here the code:

Thanks for any hints.

```
    $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            "title": {
                "text": "<span style='font-family: Helvetica'>Emissions of CO2 - from Fossil Fuels - Total (CDIAC)<\/span>",
                "useHTML": true
            },
            "yAxis": {
                "min": 0,
                "title": {
                    "text": "Gigagrams of CO2",
                    "align": "high",
                    "rotation": 0,
                    "y": -20,
                    "offset": -50
                }
            },
            "xAxis": {
                "labels": {
                    "step": 1
                },
                "tickWidth": 0,
                "showFirstLabel": true,
                "showLastLabel": true
            },
            "plotOptions": {
                "series": {
                    "connectNulls": true,
                    "shadow": false,
                    "lineWidth": 2,
                    "marker": {
                        "enabled": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "chart": {
                "renderTo": "container",
                "type": "column",
                "zoomType": "xy"
            },
            "series": [{
                "name": "Bangladesh",
                "data": [
                    [2007, 48506],
                    [2010, 56199]
                ]
            }, {
                "name": "Sri Lanka",
                "data": [
                    [2007, 12467],
                    [2010, 12720]
                ]
            }]
        });

    });
```

Comment: Is this ok? http://fiddle.jshell.net/3bcb8sxw/3/

Comment: @Hristo: Thanks a lot. I am programming & using a JSON response to generate the graph. The default format of that JSON array is the above. Would have been nice to get it working without too much change. Putting the years in the xAxis-categories means a bit of reprogramming then, which I would have liked to avoid. But I guess it's the only way to go. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should using categorized xAxis. Then you need just two small changes:

- set `xAxis.type = 'category'`
- change years into strings: `2008` -> `"2008"`

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3bcb8sxw/4/